# Exporting a Reporting Services Report to Excel and Having the table header wrap

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report in Reporting services, and when I preview it, the headers for a table wrap, but when I export it to Excel, the don't. They just get cut off.  Any ideas on how to force it to wrap when I export to Excel?

Answer (score 3):

Although this link doesn't address your question directly, its fairly comprehensive in terms of design considerations for Report Rendering in in Excel

Link: [Designing for Microsoft Excel Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159836(SQL.90).aspx)(Reporting Services)

Comment: Thanks for the link.  It doesn't talk about my issue specifically, but it is helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing report from SSRS to EXCEL and if you find some TOP column joined up then the best way to resolve this issue would be:

- Go back to report designer and adjust all your text boxes.
- Adjust to left side of the designer window. You will see a blue line when it's adjusted to left.
- Your dataset at top should also be moved toward left side of the designer window.
- You might have date time function on left adjust it to top dataset vertically with 0-1 Points gap.
- Including your header which would be Title of your company, name of report and all parameter mentioned below should be adjusted just next below to date time function which I have mentioned earlier.

Play with report designer by adjusting the text box and you will see the magic.